# How to use wget on website with Chinese characters

Tags: wget

I am attempting to generate a static version of a dynamically driven website using wget.

The problem is that when I do this on a site with Chinese characters, rather than a page of neatly formed Chinese characters I end up with garbled ascii nonsense, but still well formatted.

This is the command that I am currently running:

```
wget -P 1 -mpck --user-agent="" -e robots=off --wait 1 -E http://awebsite.com
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, I am talking in respect to actual page content and not the URLs. Cheers!

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you mean that if you browse to the site, all is well, but
if you download the page and point your browser to the downloaded file,
it’s mangled. Two suggestions:

- Check the HTML source and see if the encoding is set therein; it might be set only as HTTP metadata.
- Are you also downloading the stylesheet? Try the `-p` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--header='Accept-Language: zh'`

eg.

`wget -P 1 -mpck --user-agent="" -e robots=off --wait 1 -E --header='Accept-Language: zh' http://awebsite.com`

If that doesn't work, try checking what 'Content-Language' code comes up in the HTTP headers with:

`curl -I http://awebsite.com`